# Dynamic programming in Python - Resource Allocation

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

**Problem description:**

Suppose there are `n` Christmas trees on a farm.  You want to maximise the chance that all trees are ready for Christmas. In order to cause trees to grow more quickly, you can feed them with `m` bags of fertilizer.
You have calculated the probability that each tree will be ready on time, based on the number of bags of fertilizer you apply to it. You have a list `p[i][j]` represents the probability that plant `i` will be ready if `j` bags of fertilizer is applied. You can't split the bags and once a bag of fertilizer is applied to a tree, you can't use it for different trees.
Trees do not always grow faster with more fertilizer, so it is possible that the probabilities could decrease or increase as the number of fertilizers increases. 
 
**Find the largest probability that all the trees are fully grown by Christmas**.

**Question:**
How to solve it using dynamic programming tabulation? Please write a function which takes 3 parameters `best_allocation(number_of_trees, number_of_bags, probability_list)`. Ideally, this function returns the highest probability of all the Christmas trees can be ready for Christmas by allocating bags of fertilizers to plants optimally.

**Test cases:**

```
probs=  [[0.5, 0.5, 1],[0.25,0.1,0.75]]
best_allocation(2,2,probs)
#In this case, the best choice is to allocate 0 bags to tree0, and allocate 2 bags to tree1, 
#which gives us an overall probability of 0.75*0.5 = 0.375

probs = [[0.5, 0.75, 0.25],[0.75,0.25,0.8]]
best_allocation(2,2,probs)
#In this case, the best choice is to allocate 1 bags to plant0, and allocate 0 bags to plant1. 
#The overall probability is 0.75*0.75=0.5625
```

Comment: Hi @Ning! Could you please provide a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? You described your aim very well, but we need to see where your problem occurs.

Comment: Note that in python, comments begin with a `#`, not `//`

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a recursive function like:

```
def best_allocation(number_of_trees, number_of_bags, probability_list):
    if number_of_trees == 1:
        return max(probability_list[0][:number_of_bags + 1])
    return max(
        best_allocation(
            number_of_trees - 1,
            number_of_bags - bags,
            probability_list[1:]
        ) * probability_list[0][bags]
        for bags in range(0, number_of_bags + 1)
    )
```

If you only have one tree, then take the highest probability available (restriction is the number of bags available). If you have `n + 1` trees, then look at all possible bag allocations to the "new" tree (`+ 1`) combined with the optimal allocations of the remaining bags to the `n` trees, and then take the optimal overall outcome (`max`).

**EDIT**:
A simple way to add memoization to that would be:

```
def memo(func):
    cache = {}
    def wrapper(n, m, list_of_lists):
        args = (n, m) + tuple(tuple(list_) for list_ in list_of_lists)
        if args not in cache:
            cache[args] = func(n, m, list_of_lists)
        return cache[args]
    
    return wrapper

@memo
def best_allocation(number_of_trees, number_of_bags, probability_list):
    ...
```

Comment: Hi @Timus I am looking for a solution that finds the largest probability using memoization (dynamic programming). But a recursive solution is a really good start. Thanks a lot! By the way, any idea about how to construct a memo table and what values should we store in each cell?

Comment: @Ning Do you mean _caching_ by memoization? If I need that, I usually use the [`lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functools.html?highlight=cache#functools.lru_cache) decorator from the standard library. But part of your function arguments - the list - is non-hashable, so that's not an option. And you need to find a way around that if you build your own memo table (probably by converting the list of lists into tuples).

Comment: Hi @Timus Yes, I mean by building my own memo table,  like the memo table shown in the first two solutions of this question https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/coin-change-dp-7/